# Uncaught Error: No index defined for Password(Firebase error)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am quite new to firebase and i am trying to retrieve particular data. and getting this error,

Please help me with this.

My code looks like this

```
   var t1= this.password.value;

    var user_id = this.state.comments[2];

    firebase.database().ref(user_id).orderByChild("Password").equalTo(t1).on("child_added", (snapshot) => {

        var datas1 = []
        snapshot.forEach((data1) =>
        {

            datas1.push( {

                username: data1.val().Username,
                password: data1.val().Password,

            });

        });

        this.setState ({
            datas1: datas1,
        });

    });

    console.log(this.state.datas1);
```

even the array datas1 is coming empty.